# Handling errors in separate domains during testing

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have to listen to an event and check that a particular value is set after this event.  For example:

```
eventEmitter.on("event", () => {
    expect(thing).to.equal(otherThing);
    done(); 
});
```

This all works fine if `thing` equals `otherThing` which it should -- however, if there is something wrong and the test fails (the two are not equal) *or* there is an error in this callback (I wrote `otherTing` instead of `otherThing` for example) the error is swallowed and `done` is not called.

I understand that the issue here is that the `it` spec code and the event callback run in separate domains so the errors in the latter do not propagate to the former.

What is the proper way to handle this situation in tests?